# How to specify a controller in the content/selection Binding of an Ember.Select view?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to manually specifify the controller for an Ember.Select view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="selected-date-range">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <img class="dashboard_icon_small" src="{%=URL('static','images/calendar_dashboard_icon_small.png')%}"/>
        <h4>{{content}}
        {{view Ember.Select
          id="locatorSelector"
          contentBinding="Dashboard.LocatorSelectorController.content"
          selectionBinding="Dashboard.LocatorSelectorController.selectedLocator"
          optionLabelPath="content.label"
          classNames="pull-right"}}
        </h4>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

But that is not working. Is it possible to do that?

If I duplicate content/selectedLocator in the application (Dashboard), then I can access them like:

```
        {{view Ember.Select
          id="locatorSelector"
          contentBinding="Dashboard.locator"
          selectionBinding="Dashboard.selectedLocator"
          optionLabelPath="content.label"
          classNames="pull-right"}}
```

But I do not like to duplicate this data. Why is the controller not accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Access your desired controller's model in "contentBinding". Then you can just refer to that model directly in "selectionBinding". See below:

```
{{view Ember.Select 
                contentBinding = "controllers.selected_locator.model"
                optionLabelPath = "content.label"
                selectionBinding = "model. selectedLocator"
                classNames = "pull-right"}}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, however you have the `create` the controllers before and set their content (in the route). Have you done that?

A cleaner way would be to you include the required controller via `needs` in your current one, you can access it in your template.

Put this in your controller:

```
needs: ['selected_locator']
```

And then in your template:

```
{{view Ember.Select
          id="locatorSelector"
          contentBinding="controllers.selected_locator.content"
          selectionBinding="controllers.selected_locator. selectedLocator"
          optionLabelPath="content.label"
          classNames="pull-right"}}
```